# What IDE do you use for Mono development on KDE?

Tags: kde, mono

Currently I don't have a Linux installation with a GUI. All are running text mode. When I do, I usually use KDE. On Windows I am a .NET developer and I haven't done any Mono development, yet. I heard that Monodevelop is only for GNOME.

If you develop Mono on a KDE environment, what IDE do you use?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're really QT gungho and just can't stand any gtk+ stuff on your desktop, you might be out of luck.  If you are, on the other hand, not a library-nazi, may I suggest Monodevelop?

> [Monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) is an IDE primarily designed for C# and other .NET languages. MonoDevelop enables developers to quickly write desktop and ASP.NET Web applications on Linux, Windows and Mac OSX. MonoDevelop makes it easy for developers to port .NET applications created with Visual Studio to Linux and to maintain a single code base for all platforms.

Of course, you can also go write along using Emacs or Vim without any real problems.

Comment: I am not that advanced of a Linux user to be any kind of nazi :)
It may be just my lack of understanding that Monodevelop cannot be used on KDE. Though I started with GUI on Linux I quickly switched to text because I was always connecting using my Linux servers using SSH and didn't want waste resources on GUI. Never got around learning GUI stuff on Linux.

Comment: The more you know :)

Comment: Monodevelop is THE Mono IDE. If you really don't want to use GTK libraries, you could also use EMACS with it's Mono mode: http://www.cybercom.net/~zbrad/DotNet/Emacs/ but I really recommend Monodevelop as you IDE.

Comment: not that I don't like Vim or Emacs but seriously those are the next runners up? no love for Kate or Kdevelop? Oh well those were my answers being that they are KDE specific and very featureful,I can't speak for Mono support though, I suspect that Monodevelop is the best for developing Mono.

Comment: @xenotarracide: dully noted.  It's a question of taste, I guess.  It hardly ever occurs to me to suggest those options because I've never used them.  To be fair, they are the KDE Way of doing things.

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason you can't use Monodevelop on KDE. All GTK+ apps should work, the only real downside is it might look a little bit alien and it's going to pull in a large set of libraries that you "don't need" unless you have other GTK+ apps installed.

FWIW, I use emacs for most of my Mono development.

Answer (score 3):

The important thing to note here is that MonoDevelop works fine in KDE.  It does not require you to use GNOME.  This is true of pretty much every GTK+ application.

Comment: I installed MonoDevelop with oneclick under OpenSuse (I use KDE) and it's been installed and a shortcut placed under Development. When I click on it, it reports "The following add-ins could not be started: MonoDevelop.GnomePlatform,5". I don't have Gnome installed and yet the error is about missing Gnome Platform. If I choose to continue, I get the error "A fatal error has occured". Perhaps this is why there is this misconception MonoDevelop can not run under KDE? Anyway, in order to run it under KDE, what do I have to do?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out [KDevelop 4](http://www.kdevelop.org/) or [Kate](http://kate-editor.org/)?

Disclaimer: I don't develop mono and I haven't been able to get the vi bindings in kate to be good enough to replace vim yet.

Comment: not yet. will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) is an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) with support for Mac, Linux and Windows.